# Unity seems to have incorrectly imported materials for a character model

Tags: model, textures, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on a game and I have a model of a character, in Milkshapes he appears to be textured correctly. However in Unity the material for his eye and his body does not seem to be the correct material. Both the eye and the body of the character seem to be using a new material "No Name" that doesn't exist in Milkshapes. While the body looks okay, the eye doesn't and neither are even using the right material. Both are using the same character out of the same folder located in the Unity project.

[image]

I am almost 100% sure that Unity imported the model incorrectly, if you can help me fix this that'd be great.

Comment: You can always create a material in Unity with the eye texture and then set it manually for your eye object in the hierarchy.  If the UVs are correct, the texture should look fine.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the preferred answer for me, I seem to have quickly found sort of a work around solution that might work for other people experiencing this problem. I re-exported the model in Milkshapes (was not the original program that exported it) and re imported into Unity and it's materials appear to be correctly working now.